# Discord js role edit not changing color

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a simple command that changes the color of a role, it was working before but it suddenly stopped working. It actually works fine but it just doesn't change the color of the role.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'color') {

        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "asd");

        role.edit({
            color: '#c14a8e'
        })
        message.channel.send("Changed color.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you recieving an error? Your code is fine if your bot has the sufficient permissions. Make sure they are an administrator in the server and/or have manage roles permission. Keep in mind that if the role they are trying to edit is above their top role in the heirarchy, they will not be able to edit it despite being an administrator.

Comment: No, i dont get an error, my bot has all permissions and the role i am trying is at the bottom.